# Objecy.keys().map() VS Array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

can you give me an argument why approach A is better than approach B.

Approach A:

```
const transformCompanyOptions = (companies: Array<{id: string, name: string}>, selectedId: string) => {
  return companies.map(key => {
    return {
      value: key.id,
      label: key.name,
      checked: key.id === selectedId
    }
  })
};
```

Approach B:

```
const transformCompanyOptions = (companies: Array<{id: string, name: string}>, selectedId: string) => {
 const ret = Object.keys(companies).map((key) => {
    const newCompany = {};
    newCompany['value'] = companies[key].id;
    newCompany['label'] = companies[key].name;
    if (companies[key].id === selectedId) {
      newCompany['checked'] = true;
    }
    return newCompany;
  });
  return ret;
};
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Why would the second one be consideration at all? It's goes into a roundabout (find the key, then find the value for it in the array) trying to emulate the same functionality as a simple `Array#map`. The callback given to `Array#map` is also pure, which comes with its own implicit benefits. I can't really see why you'd want to go `Object.keys()` -> `map` -> lookup array values for anything.

Comment: Please don't tag typescript code in the JavaScript section

Comment: There are many ways to make things *more* complicated. Doesn't mean they all need to be compared…

Comment: Approach B is just trying to be Approach A with an extra step. Where approach A uses the object itself to get the values, Approach B has to use a key, to then find the object, to get the values. The key is only useful as a means to get the object, so you should prefer the approach where you have the object itself from the start.

Comment: @TKoL and if the key *is* needed for whatever reason, then you can still get if from the second parameter to the `.map` callback.

Comment: @VLAZ good point, i sometimes forget about the extra arguments `.map` gives

Answer (score 5):

Approach A is:

- shorter
- less verbose
- cleaner
- has better performance ( you need to  get all keys by `Object.keys` at first in approach B)

In addition, approach A can be improved:

```
const transformCompanyOptions = (companies: Array<{id: string, name: string}>, 
    selectedId: string) => {
  return companies.map(c => ({ 
      value: c.id,
      label: c.name,
      checked: c.id === selectedId
    }))
};
```

As @TKoL said in comments:

> Try to avoid calling the argument in `.map` as key, since
>   it's really a company itself rather than a `key` to an array

Comment: I'd also recomment not calling the argument in `.map` as `key`, since it's really a company itself rather than a key to an array.

Comment: How did you improve approach A? Maybe I don't see what you changed to my version?

Comment: @Marco no need to do `key => { return /*...*/ }` instead just do `key => /*...*/ `

Comment: @Marco `return` statement can be deleted

Comment: @TKoL thanks for the great comment. I've added to the reply. :)